# Prove the inequality $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc(a+b+c) \geq 2(ab+bc+ca)$, given $a^{2}b+b^{2}c+c^{2}a+a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}=4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a, b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that $a^{2}b+b^{2}c+c^{2}a+a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}=4$. Prove that
>   \begin{equation}
> a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc(a+b+c) \geq 2(ab+bc+ca)
> \end{equation}

Let us consider that 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{$(a+b+c)^{2}$} &=\text{$(a+b+c)(a+b+c)$} \\
&=\text{$a^{2}+ab+ac+ba+b^{2}+bc+ca+cb+c^{2}$} \\
&=\text{$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2ac+2ab+2bc$} \\
&=\text{$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2(ab+bc+ca)$}
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
and consider 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$} &=\text{$(a+b+c)^{2}-2(ab+bc+ca)$} 
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
The L.H.S of the inequality (1) 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+abc(a+b+c) $}   
&=\text{$(a+b+c)^{2}-2(ab+bc+ca)+abc(a+b+c)$} \\
&=\text{$(a+b+c)^{2}+(a+b+c)abc-2(ab+bc+ca)$} \\
&=\text{$(a+b+c)\bigg[(a+b+c)+abc \bigg]-2(ab+bc+ca)$} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I have not real proof anything yet. I have through out some work, but I have not think how would I use $a^{2}b+b^{2}c+c^{2}a+a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}=4$. Please If you any idea that would help, please write it down.

Comment: Here's something that might possibly be useful: Let $\omega=e^{2 \pi i/3}$ be the principal cube root of unity.  Then $(a+\omega b + \omega^2c)(a+\omega^2 b + \omega c)=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac.$

Comment: @ADAM I proved your inequality.

Comment: I understand. No one vote for your answer !

Comment: OK, I understood you. I'll post another solution.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove that $a+b+c\geq3$.

Let $a+b+c<3$, $a=kx$, $b=ky$ and $c=kz$, where $k>0$ and $x+y+z=3$.

Hence, $k<1$ and $4=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+a^2b^2c^2=k^3(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+k^3x^2y^2z^2)<x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+x^2y^2z^2$,
which is contradiction because we'll prove now that $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+x^2y^2z^2\leq4$.

Indeed, we need to prove that $\frac{(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)(x+y+z)^3}{27}+x^2y^2z^2\leq\frac{4(x+y+z)^6}{729}$.

But by Rearrangement $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x\leq\frac{4(x+y+z)^3}{27}-xyz$.

Hence, it remains to prove that $(x+y+z)^3\geq27xyz$, which is AM-GM.

Id est, $a+b+c\geq3$.

Hence, it's enough to prove that $9abc\geq(a+b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)$ or

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0$, which is Schur.

Done!